# Perl or VBscript: Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection

Tags: perl, vbscript

How do I make two simple scripts to do this:

[Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365743%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

I want to disable the folder redirect, install a program, then reactivate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing that from a script is pointless because it only affects that thread that called the function. It has no affect outside of the script.

Answer (score 3):

If it wasn't pointless because it only affects that thread that called the function, one would use [Inline::C](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Inline%3a%3aC), [Win32::API](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32%3a%3aAPI) or an XS module.

`script.pl`:

```
use Win32API::Wow64FsRedirection qw( :ALL );

my $saved = Wow64Disable()
   or die("Wow64Disable: $^E\n");

# ...

Wow64Revert($saved)
   or die("Wow64Revert: $^E\n");
```

`Win32API/Wow64FsRedirection.pm`:

```
package Win32API::Wow64FsRedirection;

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( state );

use Exporter   qw( import );
use Win32::API qw( );

our @EXPORT_OK = qw( Wow64Disable Wow64Revert );
our %EXPORT_TAGS = ( ALL => \@EXPORT_OK );


# On success, returns value to pass to Wow64Revert. This value will be true.
# On error, returns false and sets $^E.
sub Wow64Disable {
   state $Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection = Win32::API->new(
      'kernel32', 'Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection', 'P', 'L',
   );

   my $OldValue_buf = pack('L', 0);

   $Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection->Call($OldValue_buf)
      or return undef;

   return unpack('L', $OldValue_buf) || "0 but true";
}


# On success, returns true.
# On error, returns false and sets $^E.
sub Wow64Revert {
   my ($OldValue) = @_;

   state $Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection = Win32::API->new(
      'kernel32', 'Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection', 'N', 'L',
   );

   return $Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection->Call($OldValue);
}


1;
```